# Transfer from 3rd party IAAS cloud provider to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm being asked to define how we're going to migrate a database from a 3rd party cloud provider, which has a 12Gb DB running on a VM, with SQL 2008 R2, to Azure SQL.

And down time needs to be under an hour. We have a 1Mbit line only, so moving 12Gb, is around 30 hours. I have a few months to go live.

The plan I'm looking at is:

- Create a VM in Azure, with SQL Server 2016 on it.
- Create a replication setup, with the current live DB as a publisher, and my new DB as a subscriber.
  (Not sure how I'll go with ports and permissions - hopefully it's possible. We have full control over both the source and destination).
- Leave the system replicating for a few days. I think the initial snapshot would take a couple of days to sync up, and then, subsequent changes would be quite quick. After a few days, the destination DB will be in sync.

Once the DBs ae in sync... propose a go-live data.

On go-live:

- backup the subscriber DB
- restore it to an Azure SQL instance. (Not sure how that's done, but hopefully possible)
- Setup roles/permissions.

Change the application connection to use the new database.

Would this work?
Are there any things to know about replication? Would the snapshot generation lock the current live production DB?
Would mirroring be a better option? Not sure the option is available. Source is SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: Due to the fact that you can't use new HA features such as Distributed availability groups based on using 2008R2 version, I would rather go with log shipping or mirroring technologies rather than transactional replication.
I used all of them throughout my career, replication is the worst to troubleshoot imho. Mirroring will give you to configure it as synchronous  and automatic failover.
Log shipping will give you to opportunity to put a lag between two servers.

Comment: Another method can be using backups and pre-stage the database environment step by step. For instance, take a full backup on current cloud and restore it to Azure with no recovery option. This will takes much more time than 1 hour as you stated. Then take a diff backup from source and restore it on Azure. This will definitely take less time, then catch it with log backups. At some point, shut down the application. Take the last tail log backup and restore it. You should be able to do it in 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks for that! Nice insight and good to get info from an experienced guy. With Log Shipping and Mirroring - would I have any issues with using two VMs in separate cloud environments? Just wonder how the 'talk' to each other. For Mirroring, I'd need to setup a SQL server 2008R2 on on Azure based VM right? I think they need to be same version/edition?

Comment: Yes, quoting from MS: "For a mirroring session to be established, the partners and the witness, if any, must be running on the same version of SQL Server." Would you have issues? Most likely. I have never tried or heard this before, so I did a quick search. Looks like both is not possible with Azure DB.
Log shipping looks way better than mirroring, also this page says that mirroring is not supported(2008R2)on azure vm.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-high-availability-dr?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json